# Move file pointer to line with a known string in Python

Tags: pointers, python-2.7

I'm reading from a data file and I know my data begins after a line that contains '[Data]'.
I would like to search through the file until it reaches this line and then stops so I can begin to format the data. This is my attempt:

```
fid='myData.dat'
f=open(fid,'r')
fline = 'string'
while fline != '[Data]':
    fline=f.readline()
    print fline
```

However, it reads through every line in the document without stopping. I know for a fact that the line I want only contains [Data] and no other spaces or characters.
I'm sure there is a better way of doing this and I am open to going about this in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `'[Data]'` is followed by a `'\n'` because it's the end fo the line, so you may try `while fline != '[Data]\n':`

If you are using Windows the newline characters will be `"\r\n"`, '\n' is for Unix based systems.

Answer (score 1):

The `readline` method return line with line endings:

```
while fline != '[Data]\n':
    fline=f.readline()
```

You can strip white characters:

```
while fline.strip() != '[Data]':
    fline=f.readline()
```

If you want no space before "[", you could remove them only on right side with `.rstrip()`. You can remove only line break with `.rstrip("\r\n")`.